# Carry on Luggage size in United air line

Tags: hand-luggage

I booked the ticket for  Air Canada but they codeshare with United Airlines
I bought my carry on luggage size described by air Canada (55cm X40cmX 20), But United Airline is (22 cm x 35 cm x 56 cm)
I asked from UA via facebook. They say It will fit.  Lufthansa (56cmx40cmx23cm).

Three different sizes.

Could you pls make sure about the size of the my bag (5cm big than UA)? will have any issues ? do I have to pay more? any other alternative?

I don't want to have any trouble at Air port counter